# Error with Samsung's Zirconia license checker

Tags: android, licensing, samsung-mobile

I want to use Zirconia license checker to protect app for Samsung mobile store, so I followed [this](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/How-to-protect-your-app-from-illegal-copy-using-Samsung-Application-License-Management-Zirconia) todo and everything worked fine when I tested it, but when I generate signed apk, I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load nativeinterface from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader: findLibrary returned null
```

But when I tried to open signed .apk as zip, I saw that `\lib\armeabi\libnativeinterface.so` exists. Any ideas how it can be fixed?

Comment: Perhaps you are running applicaiton on Samsung x86 device (like Galaxy Tab 3 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is late response, but I had the same problem. I fixed the issue by renaming "armeabi" folder to "armeabi-v7a".

Comment: Don't work for me, error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.almisoft.boxtogofull-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.almisoft.boxtogofull-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libnativeinterface.so" appears only under Android 5.x Lollipop. But "libnativeinterface.so" exists under libs/arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Seems to be an issue with Android Studio and Zirconia.  I just put the question to Samsung Support.  Can't believe they don't support Android Studio yet.